# EmguCV Mat change to LineSegment2D[]

Tags: c#, emgucv, mat

I'm using emguCV houghines Method and get a Mat Object, how can I get LineSegment2D[] by this Mat.
Sample of code:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileName);
UMat uimage = new UMat();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(img1, uimage, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
UMat mat = new UMat();
CvInvoke.HoughLines(uimage, mat, 1, Math.PI / 180, 20);
```

here I can see the size is not 0, how can I get these lines, or other function to show them

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031836/how-to-use-opencv-3-0-cvinvoke-houghlines-method-with-emgucv) SO question.

Comment: Thanks, is helpful.